# Why is my mail server blacklisted (graylisting failiure)?

Tags: postfix, email-server, blacklist

My mail server was blacklisted. I fail to understand why. It was first greylisted and than it became blacklisted. Greylisting is a practice of temporary rejecting mail coming from one mail server to see if it will be resend in a reasonable time. Right?

Whit this in mind I'm posting the following mail.log section:

```
Sep 30 14:55:49 srv2 postfix/pickup[7668]: 0D07A1C0C4: uid=1020 from=<webmaster@mysite.com>
Sep 30 14:55:49 srv2 postfix/cleanup[9072]: 0D07A1C0C4: message-id=<82ffcafa92df562ebb5ccb00c322e80f@www.mysite.com>
Sep 30 14:55:49 srv2 postfix/qmgr[1268]: 0D07A1C0C4: from=<webmaster@mysite.com>, size=961, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 30 14:55:49 srv2 postfix/pickup[7668]: 153321C075: uid=1020 from=<webmaster@mysite.com>
Sep 30 14:55:49 srv2 postfix/cleanup[9072]: 153321C075: message-id=<c35124c46c0137bf05610f9a5210b4e2@www.mysite.com>
Sep 30 14:55:49 srv2 postfix/qmgr[1268]: 153321C075: from=<webmaster@mysite.com>, size=1843, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 30 14:55:49 srv2 postfix/smtp[9076]: connect to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[2a00:1450:4010:c01::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Sep 30 14:55:49 srv2 postfix/smtp[9077]: 153321C075: host mxcluster1.one.com[91.198.169.8] said: 450 4.7.1 <name.surname@recipient.se>: Recipient address rejected: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX temporary greylisted by CYREN IP reputation (in reply to RCPT TO command)
Sep 30 14:55:49 srv2 postfix/smtp[9077]: 153321C075: to=<name.surname@recipient.se>, relay=mxcluster2.one.com[91.198.169.9]:25, delay=0.49, delays=0.03/0.02/0.34/0.09, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mxcluster2.one.com[91.198.169.9] said: 450 4.7.1 <name.surname@recipient.se>: Recipient address rejected: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX temporary greylisted by CYREN IP reputation (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Sep 30 14:55:49 srv2 postfix/smtp[9076]: 0D07A1C0C4: to=<info@mysite.com>, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[64.233.162.27]:25, delay=0.7, delays=0.07/0.02/0.32/0.29, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1475240149 197si9095639ljf.84 - gsmtp)
Sep 30 14:55:49 srv2 postfix/qmgr[1268]: 0D07A1C0C4: removed

.........

Sep 30 15:03:59 srv2 postfix/qmgr[1268]: 153321C075: from=<webmaster@mysite.com>, size=1843, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 30 15:03:59 srv2 postfix/smtp[9401]: 153321C075: to=<name.surname@recipient.se>, relay=mxcluster1.one.com[91.198.169.8]:25, delay=490, delays=490/0.01/0.12/0.06, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host mxcluster1.one.com[91.198.169.8] said: 554 5.7.1 <name.surname@recipient.se>: Recipient address rejected: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX blocked, unlist at http://www.cyren.com/ip-reputation-check.html (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Sep 30 15:03:59 srv2 postfix/cleanup[9403]: 59A921C119: message-id=<20160930130359.59A921C119@srv2.company.se>
Sep 30 15:03:59 srv2 postfix/qmgr[1268]: 59A921C119: from=<>, size=4006, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 30 15:03:59 srv2 postfix/bounce[9402]: 153321C075: sender non-delivery notification: 59A921C119
```

The mail was resend 8 minutes after the greylisting and yet it was blacklisted. **WHY?**

**EDIT 1:**
This server is a shared hosting server that I administrate. I didn't notice any suspect behavior of any site hosted on this server. In total in the entire day there is about 50 emails sent by all sites and I don't see how this can be spam.

Comment: Have you tried going to the URL listed and entering the IP of your mail server?

Comment: Yes. It says my server is sending spam but it doesn't say why.

Comment: Does the mail server share an IP address with any other machines?  If you're on shared hosting, or behind a NAT firewall that shares the IP with other servers or user desktops, one of those might be the culprit instead.

Comment: No, this is a VPS with it's own IP address.

Comment: Have you actually checked your server to determine whether it has been compromised?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I just got a new IP from our hosting provider and now we got the same problem. tried to send a "unblock request" but no answer yet.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. Sent an unblock request and a day later it was removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greylisting is not a cause of your problem, your server behaved correctly. The purpose of greylist is just to check if you are able to retry (most spammers don't bother with retrying).

Then you've hit another guard, the reputation-based check. Your IP has not enough reputation and this means cyren refuses to accept your mail. [Their marketing brochure](http://www.cyren.com/tl_files/downloads/CYREN-IP-Reputation.pdf) says they could take into account any of "DNS info, geography, dynamic IPs, public RBL". While this may appear unfair, the fight against spam has truly escalated and you cannot expect everyone to just trust you and accept your emails.

I guess that if it's a true reputation system, the best way for you to fix the reputation is to kindly request anyone protected by Cyren to send you an email. This way, Cyren will note that some of "their" people find your domain name to be worthy of attention, and chances are (as they resolve domain MX and A records) this will rise also the reputation of your IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Greylisting is deferral. It will hold the message for a period of time (days sometimes) before delivering/rejecting the message. The reason why you are deferred is in the message:

Sep 30 14:55:49 srv2 postfix/smtp[9077]: 153321C075: to=, relay=mxcluster2.one.com[91.198.169.9]:25, delay=0.49, delays=0.03/0.02/0.34/0.09, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mxcluster2.one.com[91.198.169.9] said: 450 4.7.1 : Recipient address rejected: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX temporary greylisted by CYREN IP reputation (in reply to RCPT TO command))

Namely: Recipient address rejected: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX temporary greylisted by CYREN IP reputation

You should check your mail servers reputation to see if you're on any RBLs and take steps to resolve any issues.

Comment: This server is not on any blacklist that I checked, except for this CYREN. I need to understand WHY CYREN blacklisted me to prevent it from happening in the future. 

http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx - this check didn't find any blacklist record

Comment: Days?!? Graylisting for days?!? Where did you see that?